# What is the best tool to use for Linux Apache Web Server configuration and administration?

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to find the best web based tool to configure apache web server operating on redhat?

Comment: A web-based SSH applet that lets you use the command line.

Comment: There are no "best" web-based tools. The best tool is a competent system administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while ago i was forced to use plesk, but i didn't like it for various reasons.
it was quite unstable and made a open system proprietary.
after some problems with upgrades we decided to migrate to ispconfig.

either ispconfig is not perfect, but it let's you more room to configure your
server they way you like - plus it's opensource (we needed to make some changes).
it still hat some minor quirks and the ui is not the best, but it worked for us
way better than plesk.

my 2 cents: if you don't have any resellers or customers that need a web ui
please use ssh, vi and scripts or puppet to manage your webserver :) 
puppet has a very nice apache module for managing vhosts:
https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache

Answer (score 0):

If you have no apache/linux knowledge I would recommend using something like:

```
plesk or webmin (free)
```

However it is really important to know platform your app is running on and therefor either learn it yourself (plenty of resources everywhere) or get someone with knowledge to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - I do configure apache on all of our web server using terminal and editing the conf files directly but I was looking for some web interface make it faster. like copying config files is most of the content are the same or changing the ip re even the url in each config and have an overview of status of the server.

Comment: So in that case I would focus on scripts - nothing is faster than nicely scripted/automated environment.